# How to create a dynamic bootstrap carousel, using flask/python?

Tags: python, html, twitter-bootstrap, flask, jinja2

**For context:**
I'm building a social network. Just like with Facebook, each profile has a tab titled "images", which is a collection of thumbnails from the profile owner's posts.

**My goal:**
Just like with Facebook, I'd like the user navigating the page to be able to click on any thumbnail image, launching a bootstrap carousel and displaying that specific image in a much larger view. The user could then use the carousel-control class to scroll through the profile owner's other images.

**Current situation:**
The thumbnails display, you can click on any thumbnail and launch the carousel, but all of the profile owner's images appear stacked, as if they're all active.

I'm using a jinja2 for loop and a url_for statement to access the images. I also use a loop counter within an if statement to make it so only one image is active, but its obviously not working :(
It was this 4 year old [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33677374/jinja2-and-bootstrap-carousel-item-active) that I used to attempt solving this problem to begin with.

When using the carousel with a few images added statically it works properly, but I need it to be dynamic for obvious reasons.
I'm unsure how to go about showing just the specific image that was clicked on, and having the ability to scroll through the others.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

**Here is my HTML**

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    {% for post in user.posts %}
      {% if post.post_img != None %} 
        <div class="container">
          <div class="item {% if loop.counter == 1 %} active {% endif %}" id="slide{{ loop.counter }}">
            <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='post_pics/' + post.post_img) }}"> 
          </div>
          <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#pageCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon bg-primary" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#pageCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon bg-primary" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
         </a>
       </div>
     {% endif %}
   {% endfor %} 
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can move the `a` tags outside the `inner-carousel` `div`, maybe like below ( its untested)

If you look at the [documentaion](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#with-controls), the  `a` tags have to be outside.

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    {% for post in user.posts %}
      {% if post.post_img != None %} 

          <div class="carousel-item {% if loop.index == 1 %} active {% endif %}" id="slide{{ loop.index }}">
            <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='post_pics/' + post.post_img) }}"> 
          </div>

     {% endif %}
   {% endfor %} 
 </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#pageCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon bg-primary" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#pageCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon bg-primary" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this, unfortunately still has every image showing in the carousel.  I'm not sure how, but there must be a way to make it so only the clicked on image is given the active class. Right now, the loop is making it so every image has the active class.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Try with `loop.index` instead of `loop.counter`.

Comment: And have removed the container div. You can it back after the carousel works.

Comment: Funny enough I tried these suggestions last night too to no avail.  I took a look at some examples on Github, and looked at that other solution I posted in my original question, they seem to have one thing in common, they dont use url_for statements to get to the path, they simply say something like {{ images }} for example.  Therefore perhaps i should be creating an object called images set in my controller files and then use that jinja2 statement instead of the url_for.  What do you think?